# What is the difference between "text ",variable and "text "+variable in Logger

Tags: google-apps-script, logging

I have this simple Google Script script and

```
Logger.log(key + ' 1is a '+arg[key]);
```

does show the value

```
Logger.log(key + ' 2is a ',arg[key]);
```

does NOT show the value. It works ok for `console.log()`

Could anyone explain?

```
function logger() {
  
  var e ={parameters:{test:["xxx"], testID:["A87J8HR"]}, contextPath:"", parameter:{test:"xxx", testID:"A87J8HR"}, queryString:"testID:%22A87J8HR%22&test:%22xxx%22", contentLength:-1.0};

    var arg =e.parameter;
    for(key in arg){
      Logger.log(key + ' 1is a '+arg[key]);
      Logger.log(key + ' 2is a ',arg[key]);    
      Logger.log(key + " 3is a "+arg[key]);
      Logger.log(key + " 4is a ",arg[key]);     

      console.log(key + ' 1is a '+arg[key]);
      console.log(key + ' 2is a ',arg[key]);    
      console.log(key + " 3is a "+arg[key]);
      console.log(key + " 4is a ",arg[key]);     
    }
Logger.log("finished");
}
```

Corresponding log from debugger

```
7:27:46 PM Notice Execution started
7:27:45 PM Info test 1is a xxx
7:27:45 PM Info test 2is a 
7:27:45 PM Info test 3is a xxx
7:27:45 PM Info test 4is a 
7:27:45 PM Info test 1is a xxx
7:27:45 PM Info test 2is a  xxx
7:27:45 PM Info test 3is a xxx
7:27:45 PM Info test 4is a  xxx
7:27:45 PM Info testID 1is a A87J8HR
7:27:45 PM Info testID 2is a 
7:27:45 PM Info testID 3is a A87J8HR
7:27:45 PM Info testID 4is a 
7:27:45 PM Info testID 1is a A87J8HR
7:27:45 PM Info testID 2is a  A87J8HR
7:27:45 PM Info testID 3is a A87J8HR
7:27:45 PM Info testID 4is a  A87J8HR
7:29:17 PM Notice Execution cancelled
```

Comment: I think basically Logger.log is stricter than console.log, it has it's own syntax rules

Comment: Doe it mean that `Logger.log(key + ' 2is a ',arg[key]); ` is not correct syntax?

Comment: For `Logger.log`, yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation:

As you can see in the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/logger), there are only two usages of `log`:

- [Logger.log(data)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/logger#log(Object)): data is of type `object` (any `JavaScript` object `string`, `array`, `int` etc.). This particular version accepts a **single** object although you can pass multiple objects with no issue but you will get only the first one:

  ```
  Logger.log(3,4,1) // 3.0
  ```
- [Logger.log(format, values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/logger#log(String,Object...)): this particular version can be used to pass multiple objects but you need to specify the format of each object:

  ```
  Logger.log('%s %s %s', 5, 3, 10) // 5.0 3.0 10.0
  ```

In your code this `key + ' 1is a '+arg[key]` is a **single** object (a `string`), and these `key + ' 2is a ',arg[key]` are **two** objects separated by comma.

### Solution:

So in your particular scenario you can use the second version of `log` like that to be able to pass multiple objects:

```
const key = 10;
Logger.log('%s %s', key + ' 2is a ',key); // 10 2is a  10.0
```

---

On the other hand, [console.log](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log) natively supports the logging of **multiple** objects, therefore it does what `Logger.log(format, values)` can do without the need of specifying `format`:

```
const key = 10;
console.log(key + ' 2is a ',key); // 10 2is a  10
```

I would advice you to use `console.log` its usage is more straightforward if you want to print multiple objects.

### Bonus Information:

You can `Logger.log` multiple variables by **chaining** the different `log`s together:

```
Logger.log("hello world").log(5);
```

but this will print the results in two different lines.

Although it is an interesting information to know.

Comment: great, thank you also for detailed explanation